Almost all real numbers are diophantine
This is an exercise from Terence Tao's book "Analysis II".
A real number $x$ is called diophantine if:
$$\exists p,C\in\mathbb{R}_{>0} \forall q\neq 0,a\in \mathbb{Z}:|x-\frac{a}{q}|>\frac{C}{|q|^p}$$
I proved exercise 8.2.6 which says that for any $p>2,C>0$ the set: $$\{x\in[0,1]\mid|x-\frac{a}{q}|\leq\frac{C}{|q|^p}\text{ for infinitely many integers } a,q\neq 0\}$$ has Lebesgue measure $0$, and the next step is to use it to prove exercise 8.2.7, which says that almost all real numbers are diophantine.
As the hint says, I know that I can first work in $[0,1]$ and I know that I can consider only rational $p>2,C>0$, and I've seen some proofs of similar statements but for some reason I just can't seem to be able to prove this. I know it has something to do with a union or intersection of similar sets but I can't work out the specifics.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks! :)
EDIT: I fixed the inequality in the set from 8.2.6.

It's sufficient to prove that almost every $x\in [0,1]$ is diophantine.  For each rational of the form $\frac{a}{q}\in (0,1)$ for $a\in{0,2,\ldots,q-1}$, try putting a small interval of width $\frac{1}{Nq^{p-1}}$ centered at $\frac{a}{q}$.  What should $p$ be so that when you add up all the measures, it's finite?  With $C=\frac{1}{N}$, try letting $N\to \infty$.  What's leftover?

@user65023 Thanks for the answer :) But I don't really understand what you mean. Also, how can that help me prove that the set of non-diophantine numbers has measure zero?

Fix $N\in \mathbb{N}$.  For $q\in \mathbb{N}$, let $$A_{N,q}=\bigcup_{a=0}^{q-1} (\frac{a}{q}-\frac{1}{Nq^3},\frac{a}{q}+\frac{1}{Nq^3}).$$ The measure $\mu(A_{N,q})\leq q(\frac{2}{Nq^3})=\frac{2}{Nq^2}$.  Let $A_N=\bigcup_{q=1}^{\infty} A_{N,q}$.  Thus, $\mu(A_N)\leq \sum_{q=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_{N,q}) \leq(\frac{2}{N})(\frac{\pi^2}{6})$.  The points in $A_N$ are the problematic points (i.e., not diopantine) that we want to remove.  We don't want to sum over all $N$, since the series $\frac{1}{N}$ diverges.  Instead, use $N^2$ and also take the $\limsup$ of the sets $A_{N^2}$ and remove those points.  Let $$A=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{N=n}^{\infty} A_{N^2}.$$ I think you can show that $\mu(A)=0$.  That is because $\mu(A_{N^2})\leq \frac{2\pi^2}{6N^2}$, so the tail in the $\limsup$ is going to zero in measure.  Now show for $x\in [0,1]\cap A^c$, the point $x$ is diophantine.  For $x\in [0,1]\cap (\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{N=n}^{\infty} A_{N^2}^c)$, then there exists $N$ such that $x\notin A_{N^2}$.  That means $x$ is not in any of those little intervals that formed $A_{N^2}$.  Can you finish the proof from here?  What is the constant $C$, if we know $x\notin A_{N^2}$?  What is $p$?
